# Heroku node.js facebook setup problems

Tags: facebook, node.js, heroku

I took the facebook example but it does use the old versions of libraries and i had to use newer version of express as i use node v0.6.6. When i try to start the app i get Error: Cannot find module 'restler'. Has anyone got this working with newer versions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the Heroku [documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js) especially [Declare Dependencies With NPM](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-js#declare_dependencies_with_npm)
section.

After checking your `package.json` I saw that you are using old packages, `facebook-client` is right now at the version `1.6.0` (think about choosing a different wrapper for your graph requests like `fbgraph`).

The `facebook-template-node` package is clearly outdated, use it only as a reference (environment variables, Heroku custom files like the `Procfile`).

Programming node.js you should avoid old packages (unless you have a good reason and know how to fork/vendor and fix them) since the core api is changing on every major version (even if there are only small incompatibilities between 0.4.x and 0.6.x).

For a recent project involving facebook I used `authom` for authentication and `fbgraph` (actively maintained and pretty lightweight) as the API consumer.

As final advice, look for the package under active development (and look the the sources and tests), fix/fork/avoid the others.

Comment: Well i added the package.json file http://pastebin.com/4gW008vB, the problem is that most of the package versions is too old.

Comment: I think you should restart from scratch using [authom](https://github.com/jed/authom) for oAuth2 authentication if needed and [fbgraph](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph) (use my [fork](https://github.com/aliem/fbgraph) if you need to manage multiple access tokens). If you would rather go toward the template way, check the latest versions of all packages from [npm search](http://search.npmjs.org/) and test it in your environment (I think the 'facebook' package needs to go away since it has not been updated in a while).